# Is minimal cover under symmetric 3-deduction NP-complete?

Tags: graph-theory, np-hardness

Forgive me if this problem is known by another name, I do not know any references for it.

> **Symmetric deduction**. An equation $e \in E$ is a subset of variables $V$ such that knowing $|e| - 1$ of the variables allows you to deduce the missing one.
>
> **Minimal cover under symmetric deduction**. Does there exist a set of $k$ variables such that their closure under symmetric deduction with equations $E$ equals all variables $V$?

This problem is proven NP-complete [in this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/113027/is-finding-a-minimal-set-of-seed-variables-for-a-complete-deduction-of-a-system/113068#113068). There is a limited version of this problem:

> **Minimal cover under symmetric $d$-deduction**. Same as before, except $\forall e\in E: |e| \leq d$. That is, each equation has degree $d$ or lower.

This problem is trivial for $d = 2$ (choose one variable per connected component), and NP-hard for $d = 4$ as shown by Thinh D. Nugyen [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/113051/22714).

What about $d = 3$?